# Django 1.9.6 Keyrror `manager` on django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py, Line 505

Tags: django, django-models, keyerror

Lets say, I've following Django model setup like this:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

So when I'm trying to do these in Django shell

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
q.choice_set().all()
```

Instead of returning empty or anything, its simply erroring out with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/path/to/my/djangoproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 505, in __call__
manager = getattr(self.model, kwargs.pop('manager'))
KeyError: 'manager'
```

I've tried using

```
q.choice_set()
```

But nothing, same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be **q.choice_set.all()**

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
q.choice_set.all()
```

Comment: What?? Huh... I guess I was using tab `hint` which lead me to add parenthesis. Thanks man.